# How to totally disable debugging features from Visual C++?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++

Even after moving from `Debug` to `Release` mode in Visual C++ 2013 Express:

[image]

I still notice huge performance differences (on `std::vector` performance timings for example) between:

- running the .exe from inside VC++ with <kbd>F5</kbd>
- running *the same* .exe from Windows Explorer, by double-clicking on the .exe

**Is there a way, in Visual C++, to run the `.exe` you're working on without enabling any debugging feature at all?** (with a handy shortcut like <kbd>F5</kbd>) ?

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl + F5 instead?

Comment: What is performance difference on `std::vector` you are observing?

Comment: @VTT it's twice slower from inside VC++ on inserting millions of items, sorting etc.

Comment: @Asesh this seems to solve it, great! This is the answer, if you want to post it. Is there a way to make F5 produce what CTRL+F5 do?

Comment: What are the exact timings you are getting? Inserting millions (how many exactly?) of items (what kind of items?) and sorting them should not take even a second and even if it runs twice as slow it should not produce any noticeable difference. You should probably also supply a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Basj You can configure it. Go to Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard. Now search for that command and override the default keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution, thanks to @Ashesh's comment:

Menu *Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard*:

then replace the keyboard shortcut for `Debug.StartWithoutDebugging` from CTRL F5 to F5.

[image]

Comment: Since this issue has been resolved, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issue to find the answer easily. Have a nice day.